# Moving assets from Metamask on Windows to Mirai wallet on Apple

Tags: metamask

I have Metamask on a Windows laptop. It holds game assets. Now, the game has moved to the Mirai Wallet on Apple. How do I move my assets to the new wallet? Can I just use the Mirai wallet address to transfer? * can't get Mirai on Windows.*

Comment: If the game assets are NFTs or tokens in a blockchain compatible with Mirai App, then it should be possible to transfer them as any NFT or token. If the assets are in Ethereum mainnet you will need some ether to pay the transaction fees, similarly with other blockchains.